# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, datasource

I am trying to connect my Servlet to mysql database using data Source . But whenever I run my servlet I end up getting this exception :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:913)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:356)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2306)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    Servlet.AbdulTayyebs.processRequest(AbdulTayyebs.java:36)
    Servlet.AbdulTayyebs.doGet(AbdulTayyebs.java:57)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is my Content.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/abdultayyebs" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4000/abdultayyebs?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
          username="root" password="february1996" maxActive="5" maxIdle="2"
          maxWait="1000"/>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
  <resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/abdultayyebs</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth></resource-ref>
```

And here is my servlet AbdulTayyebs

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter; 
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import javax.naming.Context;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;

 public class AbdulTayyebs extends HttpServlet {

  DataSource ds=null;  

 @Override
 public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException{
    try {
     Context initContext = new InitialContext();
     Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
     ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/abdultayyebs");  
    } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new ServletException("Something went wrong while Initializing the Servlet",e);
    }
  }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,                   
       HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException,IOException {
       PrintWriter write = response.getWriter();
       try {   
       Others.Action a = Others.ActionFactory.CreateAction(request);
     try(Connection c=ds.getConnection()){
     String page = a.Execute(c,request,request.getSession(false));
       request.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(request, response); 
      }      
   }     
   catch (SQLException e) {
     write.println(e);
   }
   catch (ServletException e) {
     write.println(e);     
   }
   catch (Exception e) {       
    write.println(e);
   }   
 }

 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      processRequest(request, response);
   }

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     processRequest(request, response);
     } 
   }
```

I also added the mysql jdbc driver in the lib folder of tomcat but even this didnt helped ? It would be highly appreciable if anybody can help me out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z*

This means that the MySQL JDBC driver is outdated as such that it doesn't support Java 1.6's [`Connection#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid-int-) method.

[Upgrade it](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). And make sure that you've only one MySQL JDBC driver JAR file in the runtime classpath.

#### See also:

- [Connect Java to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database/2840358#2840358)

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful

Comment: I had an error similar to this but with an Oracle DB.  Upgrading the driver fixed it.

Comment: Any other possibilities for this? I'm using the newest version of MySQL Connector (8.0.18 at time of writing) but I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: @JRSofty: then you don't have only one MySQL JDBC driver JAR file in the runtime classpath as indicated by the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the solution was not to upgrade my driver (JT400).  Even the latest version (9.1) appears to not have implemented isValid() (it's commented out in the code?).

What worked for me was to provide a validationQuery to my database connection pool.  E.g.:

```
validationQuery=SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share your code for doing this? I tried doing it like... 
config.addDataSourceProperty("validationQuery", "SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1");

Comment: validationQuery was a property of the connection pool I was using.  It went alongside other properties like URL, username, and password in my config files.

Comment: How to do it with Java code... config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1");

Comment: Are you using a connection pool?  Your code looks correct, so I'm guessing you might not be using a pool or that the pool you're using doesn't support that property.  If you are and it does, you'll have to check the docs for that pool.  That said, it's unusual to configure a connection pool in code.  Consider doing it through a config file.

Comment: You're correct. I'm using a Hikari connection pool. Sorry. I probably shouldn't have posted that here.

Comment: The HikariCP docs mention a property called "connectionTestQuery"  that sounds like the equivalent of the "validationQuery" I"m using.  They say you should use if your driver doesn't support JDBC 4, which was the case in my instance.

Answer (score 5):

`net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection` doesn't implement `isValid()`

So you need to specify a connection-test-query to ensure that `isValid()` method isn't called
Adding the following line to `application.properties`file resolved the error for me.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I upgraded ojdbc from verion 14 to 6. I had artifact ojdbc14, then I changed it to ojdbc6. I lost quite sometime here, as I thought 14 is a later version as 14>6. but 14 is meant for java 1.4. 6 means java6

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing using jt400 for DB2 , this worked out for me
validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is what I read about isValid method ([source](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Behavior-of-connection-Isvalid-on-a-multithreaded-connection)).
The driver (here MySQL) tries to check if your connection is valid or not. 
Not sure how it works (as it doesn't allow to connect even when my MySQL instance/service is up and running).
So, use the below string in your spring application.properties file

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=select 1 from dual
(or any test query, - select sysdate from dual)

Answer (score -1):

For me, I added the **validationQuery** parameter within the database connection pool config.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/abdultayyebs" auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4000/abdultayyebs?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
      username="root" password="february1996" maxActive="5" maxIdle="2"
      maxWait="1000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```