# A Stranger Error of database in Intellij IDEA

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I got a error called `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z` when I connected IDEA with mysql database.
I think my configuration is correct as below.In addition, the test is successful.
[The configuration pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9s9s.jpg)

And then the something stranger happened. I cannot get the any schemes from my database on the database tool window,but I can get them with Navicat. When I type `SELECT * FROM message` into console, that error appeared as below.

```
[2017-03-29 17:51:28] java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteConnectionImpl.isValid(RemoteConnectionImpl.java:108)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[2017-03-29 17:51:28]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I search Internet for this question via google, then I upgrade mysql driver  to even ver.5.1.40.But it doesn't work as well.
[The driver pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH0G0.jpg)

So, How to deal with this error? It stuck me two days.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing to the older version of IDEA.
When I used the database of IDEA of Version 2016.1.4, it did work.

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783706/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-com-mysql-jdbc-connection-isvalidiz)

This will help you.

I think you have to remove the previous MySQL driver.

Comment: I upgraded the MySQL driver, But it doesn't work and there is only one driver used by Intellij IDEA which is got from Intellij itself.

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: java version: 1.8.0_71

Comment: try to update your JDK from oracle JDK to open JDK 1.8. this link will help you 
    https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203366264-MySQL-connection-jdbc-com-mysql-jdbc-Connection-isValid-I-Z-SOLVED-

Comment: I downloaded the  IntelliJ x64 JDK from link given by Eugene Morozov and unzipped it. Then, Set the the unzip directory as IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable.But it still didn't work. Afterwards, I downloaded a latest Version of Intellij IDEA and installed it.It also didn't work.Why?

Comment: can you please attach the screen shot?