# Servlet.service() for servlet [...] in context with path [/...] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, datasource

I am trying to set a DataSource connection; the error I actually get is `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z`

but the title's error pops up right above.

--

I have a caffeJdbc.java servlet with this DataSource setting

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/caffeDB");
Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
```

--

This is the project web.xml setting, with servlet mapping and resource references

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tjdbc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>caffeJdbc</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tjdbc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/caffeJdbc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/caffeDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

--

server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
 <Resource name="jdbc/caffeDB" 
 global="jdbc/caffeDB"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/caffe"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

--

And this is the context.xml

```
<Context path="/JDBCDataSource">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/caffeDB"
        name="jdbc/caffeDB"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </ResourceLink>
</Context>
```

I loaded both JDBC driver and the commons-dbcp2-2.1.1 one in the lib directory and in the path

Comment: May be JDBC driver is outdated. Look this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783706/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-com-mysql-jdbc-connection-isvalidiz

Comment: I thought it was the last one released but, since you told me to, I checked and it was a 2007 one..
If you repost this as an answer I'll be happy to upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the JDBC Driver you are using is outdated, Please check that, You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783706/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-com-mysql-jdbc-connection-isvalidiz) for more info.